# doxygen source /test is not a readable file or directory... skipping

Tags: c++, warnings, documentation, doxygen

I'm getting a warning while compiling my documentation using Doxygen: `source /test is not a readable file or directory... skipping.`, test folder is inside my package, and contains some `.cpp` files.
Part of my `Doxyfile.in` is:

```
INPUT                  =  @CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR@/
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXAMPLE_PATH           = @srcdir@/test
```

Can you please tell me how can I get rid of this warning cleanly? thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04, Doxygen version: 1.8.17

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Which OS are you using? What is the protection of the file / directory? Looks a bit like you use a `Doxyfile.in` that is not properly translated by CMake, shouldn't `srcdir` be `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`?

Comment: @albert thanks for your kind comment, I added OS, doxygen version to the question, the file is not protected, any user has read/write access, I'm not much familiar with the `Doxyfile.in`, changing the `srcdir` to `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.17 is a bit older, December 27, 2019, the current doxygen version is 1.10.0. The `Doxyfile.in` is / should be most likely transformed in the CMake process into a `Doxyfile` which is given to the doxygen process. Woth further information about the CMake part and the starting directory etc. it is not possible to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced this line: `EXAMPLE_PATH = @srcdir@/test` with `EXAMPLE_PATH           =` , hence the warning disappeared.